# Dynamic chage value in Dialog with jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I made **popupDialog** with **jQuery Mobile**.

I'm trying to change values dynamicaly in this dialog, like 'XXXXX' and 'YYYYY' parts below code. The value is supposed to be changed before **popupDialog** show up.

My idea is try to select these parts with **jQuery** selector when pop up show.

```
$('#content').val('CHANGED VALUE');
```

However it does not work and I don't know that is correct way.

```
<div id="popupDialog" style="max-width: 400px;" data-role="popup" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="b" data-dismissible="false">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>XXXXX</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-content" role="main">
    <h3 id="content" class="ui-title">YYYYY</h3>
    <p></p>
      <a class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" href="#" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
      <a class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" href="#" data-transition="flow" data-rel="back">OK</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The values come from select box value you selected.
Are there any idea for it?

Comment: Are you trying to change `value` onload?

Comment: I'm trying to change value onload at first. Then I want to change value that is same as select box when popup show up, before form submit.

Comment: Look like you run your code after `dialog`, run your code after dialog open.

Comment: `$('#popupDialog #content').text('CHANGED VALUE');` Use `.text()` for text. `.val()` for form elements.